# Disable Crossfire on an ATI HD 5970

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, amd-catalyst, opencl

I'm trying to create a computation cluster using ATI GPUs. The problem is that I have to disable Crossfire in order to get maximum performance out of the ATI Radeon HD 5970 I bought to get started, but no matter what I do I can't disable it. The problem is that I'd like to run an OpenCL application on the two cores in parallel, but right now they just interfere with each other.

Any idea on how to do so under Ubuntu Linux, with ATI Catalyst 10.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
aticonfig --adapter=all --initial -f
```

This should "cheat" xorg into thinking you have a separate X display connected to every GPU, thus disabling Crossfire